# Get data from a api service without refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I use a spring boot with angular .right now is i have a method which allows to bring the data from api service every second but but a message that is displayed:

> core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream
>   was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or
>   Iterable.

```
//service
    ListAutombilesAuto(){
        let headers=new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':this.jwt});
      return this.fiches=this.http.get(this.BaseUrl+'/Automobiles',{headers:headers}).pipe
      (
        merge(this.fiches, interval(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.fiches)))
      );

      }

    //component
    ListAuto(){

        this.auth.ListAutombilesAuto().subscribe(data=>{
          this.fiches=data;
          console.log(this.fiches);
        }) // api call

    }
```

is there any solutions?
thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing `this.fiches` within its first assignment, therefore its value is still `undefined`.

Try fix your code as following:

```
ListAutombilesAuto() {
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': this.jwt });

  this.fiches = this.http.get(this.BaseUrl + '/Automobiles', { headers: headers });

  return this.fiches.pipe
    (
      merge(this.fiches, interval(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => this.fiches)))
    );
}
```

But actually why not keep it simple:

```
 ListAutombilesAuto() {

   let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': this.jwt });

   return timer(0, 1000)
     .pipe(
       switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.BaseUrl + '/Automobiles', { headers }))
     )

 }
```

Comment: Try websocket springboot with angular

Comment: @abhinavxeon what do you mean by that?

Comment: you can implement websocket with spring boot so in that case you will get live data without refresh

Comment: but the problem of web socket is not secure ,i think facebook now use like http polling